# Alternative to odbc package for Oracle R

Tags: r, oracle, odbc

I was wondering how people generally connected to Oracle Databases in R. Currently I am using the odbc package and I was wondering if there was a faster alternative. I looked at ROracle, but it seems to involve downloading and using an older version of R (I am currently using R 4.0). Are odbc and ROracle the only options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [odbc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odbc/index.html) and [ROracle](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/index.html) are the two best packages for connecting to an Oracle database. Both are based on DBI and require the Oracle instant client to be installed on the system.

`odbc` is available as a binary on CRAN. As `ROracle` requires the Oracle instant client to build the package, the binary must be [downloaded from Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html) or installed from source, which can be [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ROracle+%5Br%5D+install). With both packages, I have experienced difficulties in initial setup.

As far as the user interface is concerned, `ROracle` and `odbc` are very similar but there are subtle differences. For example, `ROracle` does not have a `dbBind` function, instead passing a data.frame with bind data to `dbSendQuery`. There may also be minor differences when using `dbplyr`.

In the olden days, people used the [RODBC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/index.html) and [JDBC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html) packages. These are still being maintained. In my experience though, these are considerably slower than `ROracle` or `odbc`. I would consider them to be legacy packages that should not be considered for new projects.